# Typescript generic for function that can receive multiple array of functions for pipe

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have function that can receive object that have multiple arrays of functions that will using like functions for pipe

I find generic that can validate that functions in pipe have compatible types but I still search method for make possible that this array of pipe will more that one in function

This is function that should validate that each output coincide with next input

```js
type Chain<T extends any[], A extends ((x: any) => any)[] = []> =
  T extends [infer T0, infer T1, ...infer TR] ? Chain<[T1, ...TR], [...A, ((e: T0) => T1)]> : A;


function hooks<A, B>(args: Chain<[A, B]>): Chain<[A, B]>;
function hooks<A, B, C>(args: Chain<[A, B, C]>): Chain<[A, B, C]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]>;
function hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K>(args: Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K]>): Chain<[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K]>;
function hooks(args: any) {
  return args;
}
```

And this is main goal

```js
function use<
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K,
A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1, I1, J1, K1,
A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2, I2, J2, K2,
A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3, I3, J3, K3
>(data: {
  before?: typeof hooks<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K>,
  after?: typeof hooks<A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1, I1, J1, K1>,
  some?: typeof hooks<A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2, I2, J2, K2>,
  each?: typeof hooks<A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3, I3, J3, K3>,
}) {
  return data;
}


const a = use({
  before: [
    (e: number) => e,
    (e) => e,
  ],
  after: [
    (e: string[]) => e[0],
    (e) => e.length,
    e => e * 5
    e => e.toString(),
    e => e.window  /// ts should show error
  ]
})
```

Comment: In general, when you needed a variable amount of type arguments, you would need to use an array/tuple. I think you'll need to do that here.